# Unable to build a docker container

Tags: laravel, docker, dockerfile

I'm using laravel and on my localhost I'm trying to run `./sail up -d` but when it gets to the `apt-get update` part I get this

```
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update]: exit code: 100
```

and this is my docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:21.04

LABEL maintainer="Taylor Otwell"

ARG WWWGROUP
ARG NODE_VERSION=16

WORKDIR /var/www/html

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TZ=UTC

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update

RUN setcap "cap_net_bind_service=+ep" /usr/bin/php7.4

RUN groupadd --force -g $WWWGROUP sail
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --no-user-group -g $WWWGROUP -u 1337 sail

COPY start-container /usr/local/bin/start-container
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY php.ini /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["start-container"]
```

I've tried doing it manually, for example instead of doing `./sail up -d` I would run `sudo apt-get update`, but that didn't work.

Comment: You don't say what problem is actually leading `apt-get` to fail, but in this Dockerfile it looks like it should be fine to just delete the `RUN apt-get update` line; you're not using the Debian APT package cache at all.  For Docker layer-caching reasons, if you're going to `apt-get install` something, `apt-get update` needs to be in the same `RUN` line in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu stopped supporting the 21.04 release in January 2022. This is why you are getting this unexpected error. The 21.04 is a short-lived interim release, I suggest that you use an LTS release instead, 22.04 or 20.04:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
```

LTS releases are the ‘enterprise grade’ releases of Ubuntu and are used the most. An estimated 95% of all Ubuntu installations are LTS releases.

Read more about Ubuntu release cycle - https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle.